# Oracle analytical query to group rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table which has 2 columns tsf_no and item, one tsf_no can have more than 1 item. I want to have a query which will assign sequential numbers (say thrd_id) to each n lines. this n is a variable. I have written a query which is not quite there yet. Note: 4 is n (variable). It assigns sequential numbers to each n line but tsf_no 100018628942 is there in both thrd_id in 1 and 2 which I don't want.

expected outcome

[image]

if n = 2  then the outcome will be

[image]

```
    WITH 
    thrd_tbl AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT tsf_no,
                    thrd_id,
                    item
      FROM (SELECT tsf_no,
                   item,
                   CEIL(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tsf_no,item)/**4**) thrd_id
              FROM tsf_item))
    SELECT * FROM thrd_tbl;



    CREATE TABLE TSF_ITEM(TSF_NO NUMBER(12),
                          ITEM   VARCHAR2(25))

    /
    REM INSERTING into TSF_ITEM
    SET DEFINE OFF;
    Insert into TSF_ITEM (TSF_NO,ITEM) values (100018628027,'313549828');
Insert into TSF_ITEM (TSF_NO,ITEM) values (100018628027,'313815940');
Insert into TSF_ITEM (TSF_NO,ITEM) values (100018628027,'314075650');
Insert into TSF_ITEM (TSF_NO,ITEM) values (100018628942,'308708641');
Insert into TSF_ITEM (TSF_NO,ITEM) values (100018628942,'308708688');
Insert into TSF_ITEM (TSF_NO,ITEM) values (100018628942,'309959701');
Insert into TSF_ITEM (TSF_NO,ITEM) values (100018630248,'313870503');
Insert into TSF_ITEM (TSF_NO,ITEM) values (100018630248,'313870507');
Insert into TSF_ITEM (TSF_NO,ITEM) values (100018630289,'312547432');
Insert into TSF_ITEM (TSF_NO,ITEM) values (100018630289,'312547433');
Insert into TSF_ITEM (TSF_NO,ITEM) values (100018630289,'312547437');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused.  Your results don't need any "4" in them.  You can just use:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tsf_no)
```

Perhaps this solves your problem.  If not, you should provide clearer data on what you want to do.

Comment: as I said 4 is a variable. it can be 2,3, or n . it basically dictates how many rows will be assigned the same sequence. check my 2 samples screenshot